# Service call returning false

Tags: ros, call-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to make a service call that keeps returning false using c++ code but works fine in the command line.
Can't find much information on reasons for the call function to return to or failure causes.

Here is the command line call:

```
rosservice call /service/url "request: '1.0'"
```

Outcome:

```
[Cheery success message from server]
```

And the cpp code:

```
bool ExampleListener::send(const std::string& _request, std::string& _resp) {
  namespace__::ss::Request rosRequest;
  rosRequest.request = _request;
  namespace__::ss::Response rosResponse;

  if(client.call(rosRequest, rosResponse)) {
      _resp = rosResponse.response;
      return true;
  }else {
      ROS_ERROR("Call to server failed, because of reasons.");
      return false;
  }
}

// some other place in code
std::string _resp;
send("1.0", _resp);
```

The service is defined as follows:

```
string request
---
string response
```

Outcome:

```
[ERROR] [1470218877.683985359, 8.242000000]: Call to server failed, because of reasons.
```

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240994/service-call-returning-false/) by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2016-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case this helps anybody, what I did to make it work was to create the server as temporary (which I'm assuming is what is done in the command line call).

Why this works, I have no idea. If anyone figures it out please share.

---

Originally posted by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) with karma: 122 on 2016-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yijiangh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28469/yijiangh/) on 2017-05-14**:
Hi kotoko,

I encountered the same problem.

My case is that I was holding the service server in a standalone server and have service call in a qt-pushbutton slot function, but the service client failed to connect the service. Could you specify more on how do you "create the server as temporary"?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my scenario, the problem is that my serviceClient is initialized before my service server node is launched. For RvizPanel UI service request for a standalone node, please check this [amazing discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swri-ros-pkg-dev/nKf0h1O0h1o) (and code!) from Victor L.

---

Originally posted by [yijiangh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28469/yijiangh/) with karma: 131 on 2017-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1